# Front/Back imbalances

Tags: muscle-imbalance

Is there some combination of exercises that "automatically" will improve on front/back imbalances in the body?

How important is form for improvement of front/back imbalances?

Comment: If you have any specific concerns regarding your own imbalances, you might want to give some more information on your specific case (maybe in a new question), so we can give better advice. If you were only interested in that topic theoretically, ignore this comment :p

Comment: It is not "theoretical". I have a lot of imbalances (like very stiff one one side of the body) - but I don't know if and how I have strength imbalances

Answer (score 2):

No exercises will automatically improve imbalances. It is important to work on the specific imbalance one might have.

For instance, if someone is kyphotic they should certainly put more of an emphasis on rowing type movements to improve the strength of the back muscles. Doing the same amount of pushing and pulling work will not yield any change in the issue.

Form also plays a huge role in the fixing of muscle imbalances. Two examples where this point can really be seen would be the row and squat. If a person performs a row while in flexion, they will not be helping their body get back to extension as it should be.

As for the squat, not hitting parallel would not help the imbalance between the quads and hamstrings. Since only when the lifter is squatting down to parallel do the hamstrings really come in to play.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear from the question as to whether you are looking for a program to correct an imbalance or prevent one?

If you are trying to prevent one you could use supersets.  This is where instead of having a rest inbetween sets.  You work the opposite muscle.  For a muscle to be working, the opposing muscle must be at rest.  So for example. You could work biceps immediately followed by triceps.  Back followed by chest.  That way you can make sure you are working back and front equally.

If you are looking to correct an imbalance you would need to be more specific in your question.

Form is very important for many reasons.  To prevent an imbalance, to get the most benefit from the exercise and to prevent injury.

Comment: Regarding supersets, I feel it should be pointed out that the term is kinda squishy, as several concepts have been mashed together under that name over time. While I agree on _antagonistic supersets_ being good against imbalances, others, like _same muscle supersets_ (e.g. bench press, then flyes) might not be.

Comment: Yes I agree, which is why I explain what I meant, but good to point it out, as maybe confusing if super setting is googled

Comment: " whether you are looking for a program to correct an imbalance or prevent one?" - - - - - I want that what I do contribute to a more balanced body, like I think the Convict Conditioning Program I am following.

Comment: Reg "superset" - what would be interesting is if you could have matching goals on the 2 sides - like if you can do 8 pullups you should be able to do 17 pushups.  IS this possible?